# C - How to print only the largest number in a for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, printf, max, reverse

I am having a go at Project Euler question 4 - Finding the highest palindrome from a product of two 3-digit numbers. I have found many solutions online, none of which answer the issues I am experiencing with my own code. I am not an experienced coder and have just starter learning recreationally.

My code so far does a for loop which generates all of the numbers that are palindromes. Currently I have it printing all of them just to check that it is working, which it appears to be. I was wondering if there was a way to print only the largest number in the loop? I don't think running through manually is the most efficient way of doing it.

Here is the code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
int a,b,c,d;

for(a=100;a<=999;a++){
    for(b=100;b<=999;b++){
        c=a*b;
        d=reverse(c);
        if(c==d){
            printf("%d is a palindrome\n",c);
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}

int reverse(int number){
    int answer=0;
    while(number!=0){
    int units=number%10;
    answer=answer*10+units;
    number=number/10;
}
return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the largest result to a variable.  Then when you find another that is bigger, update that variable.

Then when the loop is complete, print the result from the variable which is the largest.

I'll let you work out the code.  It's trivial.