# How to get the highest number between other numbers - C

Tags: c

I've been trying to do a exercise that I have to input a name and a score to 16 candidates. Then the program should return who's the winner (name and score). I'm new into programming and I'm struggling with this program. In my mind I have to get the highest number between these 16 inputs but i have no clue how to do this, that's the part that broke me. Tried a lot of things and nothing worked.

```
    for(candidates = 16; candidates >= 0; candidates--){
    
         printf("\n******************COMPETITION MISS EXTREMA******************\n");
         printf("Input candidate name: ");
         scanf("%s", name);
         printf("Input candidate score:e %s: ", name);
         scanf("%f", &score);
         printf("Candidate: %s  Score: %.2f", name, score);  
             
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C - How to print only the largest number in a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40119577/c-how-to-print-only-the-largest-number-in-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Create a `maximumScore` variable and each time you input a score, compare the score with the maximumScore. If the score is greater than maximumScore, update maximumScore with score and continue the process until you complete the execution of for loop.
Finally print the `maximumScore` to get the maximum number.

```
    float maximumScore = 0.0;
    for(candidates = 16; candidates >= 0; candidates--){
    
         printf("\n******************COMPETITION MISS EXTREMA******************\n");
         printf("Input candidate name: ");
         scanf("%s", name);
         printf("Input candidate score:e %s: ", name);
         scanf("%f", &score);
         printf("Candidate: %s  Score: %.2f", name, score);   
         if (maximumScore < score) {
                  maximumScore = score;
         }   
    }

    printf("Maximum Score: %f", maximumScore);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This tracks the best score; it doesn't track the name of the user with that best score.